# Tikz showing exponential curve with labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to recreate this image from a presentation:

[image]

I got part of the way there with the following:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (0,5) node[left]{price}-- (0,0) -- (8,0) node[below] {time};
\draw[thick] (0, 4) -- (1.5, 4) ;
\draw[thick] (1.5, 4) -- (1.5, 2) ;
\draw[thick, domain=0:4] plot({\x+1.5},{(4 - (2 * exp(-\x/2)))}) ;
\draw[thick] (5.5, 3.73) -- (8, 3.73) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

But it's unclear to me how to add the remaining labels and arrows.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By doing all lines on one path you can improve the corners.

The rest is just adding nodes at the appropriate corners. I set the “pre-trade” node above the graph, similar to the post one to have a better consistency.

The LaTeX-wide knows macro `\\` does only work in a node if the `align` key is set.

Note that I added three coordinates to the path:

- `pre`,
- `low`, and
- `post`

which are later used to extract the *y* values for the arrows. This way, if you change something in your graph, you don’t need to adjust the arrows.

Additionally I used another macro `\arrowlength` that specifies the length of the arrow as it is used a few times on the arrow path. I macro-ized the *x* value of the arrow bar/link in the same way.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*{\arrowBar}{9cm}
\newcommand*{\arrowlength}{.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\tiny}]
\draw[<->,every node/.style={font=\normalsize}] (0,5) node[left]{price} -- (0,0) -- (8,0) node[below] {time};
\draw[thick] (0, 4) -- (1.5, 4)  node[midway, above, align=center]        {pre-trade\\equilibrium}
                        coordinate (pre)
                    -- (1.5, 2)  node[left,midway,align=right]            {200 shares\\sold}
                                 node[right]                              {trade print}
                                 coordinate (low)% this coordinate could have been produced with the preceding node too
                    -- plot[domain=0:4]({\x+1.5},{(4 - (2 * exp(-\x/2)))}) 
                    -- (5.5, 3.73)
                    -- (8, 3.73) node[midway,above]                       {post-trade equilibrium}
                                 coordinate (post);

\tikzset{every node/.append style={right, align=left}}
\draw[<->] let \p1=(pre), \p2=(low), \p3=(post) in
       (\arrowBar-\arrowlength,\y1)
    -| (\arrowBar,\y3)
       node[pos=.75] {permanent\\impact}
    |- (\arrowBar-\arrowlength,\y2)
       node[pos=.25] {temporary\\impact};
\draw[ ->] let \p3=(post) in
       (\arrowBar,\y3) -- ++ (-\arrowlength,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]